# Hover image HTML : responsive?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create 2 hover images in a row in wordpress with this simple html code (see below).

```html
<a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src:'image2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src:'image1.jpg'"></a>
```

However whenever I modify another module from that same page, not only the hover is no longer responsive there is no record of the HTML code being written in the first place in the module. Is there a way to "protect" my code from being overridden ? Like a   to avoid missing spaces. 
On another matter I would also like that code to be responsive : whenever I make my screen smaller the images are not in the same position. (No javascript please juste CSS and simple ! I'm a newbie)

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you !

Comment: can you paste your HTML code into the question? Also since this doesnt seem to have anything to do with wordpress, I'd suggest removing that tag, and keeping the question simple in scope.

Comment: I'm using <a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src:'image2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src:'image1.jpg'"></a> as mentioned above it DOES work ! The only problem is when I modify other modules in my page and then the code no longer works and is actually missing...

Comment: @Elisap you need to edit your question and include all HTML and CSS that you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two images like given below ( Using Css):

```
    a:hover:after {
    content: url(image/circle.PNG); 
    display: block;
    }

    a:hover {
     content: url(image/anyother.PNG); 
     display: block;
   }
```

Thanks, 
Hope this will help